# CountDownLatch issue in android

Tags: android, countdownlatch

I am using countdownlatch as in example below. Here BackgroundDataPopulator creates an AyncTask which in turn invokes displayData in PackagePopulator. But it never happens and the activity gets stuck. What am I doing wrong here.

```
public class PackagePopulator implements ServerDataProcessor {

    private CountDownLatch counter=new CountDownLatch(1);
    String[]  packages;

    public void getPagesFromServer() {
        new BackgroundDataPopulator(IMgrApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.list),new PData(),this).execute();

    }

    public String[] getPages() {
        try {

            counter.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            packages=new String[0];
        }
        return packages;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayData(ServerOutput output) {


        Page[] pgArray = new Page[((PageData)output).getPages().size()];
        pages=new String[pgArray.length];
        pgArray = ((PageData)output).getPages().toArray(pgArray);
        for(int i=0;i<pgArray.length;i++){
            pages[i]=pgArray[i].getName();
        }
        counter.countDown();

    }

}





public class BackgroundDataPopulator extends AsyncTask<Void, String, ServerOutput> {
    // connector=new JSONConnector();
    Connector connector;
    String curUrl;
    ServerOutput curServerOutput;
    ServerDataProcessor processor;


    public BackgroundDataPopulator(String url, ServerOutput serverOutput,ServerDataProcessor curProcessor) {
        //connector = new UnitTestConnector();
        connector = new JSONConnector();
        curUrl = url;
        curServerOutput = serverOutput;
        processor=curProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerOutput doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return connector.getData(URLUtils.getFormattedUrl(curUrl),curServerOutput);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerOutput output) {
        processor.displayData(output);
        //Toast.makeText(BaseFragmentActivity.this, "Done!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pagePopulator=new PagePopulator();
    pagePopulator.getPagesFromServer();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> getSpinnerDataArray(String item) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,pagePopulator.getPages());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you are doing and where the AscynTask is being started. It looks like you are calling `await()` and `countDown()` on the same thread and that is why you are getting blocked. Post more details and/or debug your code.

Comment: I modified code a bit to add execute for backgroundtask. But to answer your question, displayData is being invoked by AsyncTask thread created in onCreate method

Comment: Who and when is calling `PackagePopulator.getPages()`?

Comment: That is called by the activity which uses PackagePopulator to get data from server, I edited code above

Comment: I still don't see any calls to `PackagePopulator.getPages()`. In any case, does `doInBackground()` get executed at all?

Comment: That was a typo, its getting called in getSpinnerDataArray above, also doInBackground gets called but not onPostExecute

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your use of `CountdownLatch` doesn't make sense (at least to me). As for why it blocks, you are calling `await()` on the UI thread, and then `countDown()` is supposed to be called on the UI thread as well. Obviously this is not going to work.

Comment: Ok that could be the problem. I want my UI thread to wait when calling getPages if the data is not yet downloaded from server

Comment: You shouldn't block the UI thread, _ever_. Just display a progress dialog or something and when the data is downloaded (or an error occurs), `onPostExecute()` will be called and you can update your UI accordingly. You don't need the `CountdownLatch` for this, just `AsyncTask`.